# How might I achieve this blurred text-outline effect with ImageMagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

https://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/1517996/1106095757/stock-photo-photographer-silhouette-people-make-a-photo-of-nature-landscape-for-photostocks-and-social-networks-1106095757.jpg

I'm interested in creating a similar effect for watermarking images on my site.

I need to generate it on the fly as the text in the middle would be different on each photo, so I can't use a precomposed png file.

I'm not bothered about the exact font (I have one I'm happy with), but how can I go about adding a nicely blurred outline around it like they have?

I tried using `gaussianBlurImage` but it doesn't work on an ImagickDraw object.  Do I need to compose my ImagickDraw onto an Imagick object first, then blur it, then compose it onto the main image?

Or are there some clever ImagickDraw functions I can use that I've not discovered yet?

Thanks

Comment: This looks more like a **stroke** to me ... IE --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840544/php-imagickdraw-with-outlined-text-issues

Comment: Hmmm, thanks.  The problem is when I set the stroke to (say) 5, it overlaps the letters a lot, rather than sitting outside the letters.  I.e. if you have black fill and white stroke and go thick enough with the stroke you completely lose the black - the stroke radiates out AND in, rather than just out.

Comment: It looks partially opaque, not blurred. A common method for achieving that effect would be to use a stroke width of several pixels with the same semi-transparent color for both stroke and fill, then draw or annotate a second time with another semi-transparent fill color and a stroke color of none.

Comment: The problem is where the letters go ends up grey.  You get semi-transparent white from the stroke of the first annotation, and then semi-transparent black from the second annotation.

If I was happy having a solid colour for the text I agree it'd work perfectly - but I want a thick stroke making the photo lighter, and then a fill colour making the photo darker.  Your suggestion unfortunately makes the photo... greyer.  Unless I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I suspect what I need to do is write white semi-transparent text.  Convert to image.  Blur it.  Then somehow create a mask from a second un-blurred annotation, chop that OUT of the blurred image, and then add the darker semi-transparent text inside the blurred outline.  Phew.  I'm just worried I'll go to the effort of doing all that and it'll end up looking rubbish for whatever reason!

Comment: I do a lot of text manipulation with command line ImageMagick. To get the effect in your sample, I'd probably create a transparent canvas the size of the input image, draw the text with white and a wide white stroke, blur that image, and draw the text again over that with black and no stroke. Then I'd reduce the opacity of that overlay image and composite it onto the original input. Often I get better results by creating that overlay at 200% (or more) of the input dimensions, then resize it down just before compositing. I wouldn't know how to do it with Imagick or php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in ImageMagick, by creating a transparent background and adding text via label: using black text with a white stroke and then reducing the opacity. Then composite that latter onto your original.

Original:

[image]

```
convert image.jpg \( -background none -pointsize 64 -fill black -strokewidth 2 -stroke white -font arial -gravity center label:"stockphoto" -channel a -evaluate multiply 0.33 +channel \) -gravity center -geometry +0+50 -compose over -composite result.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: It happens that I've decided to move in a different direction, due to the dynamic nature of the text I want to place.  In extreme circumstances it's only 3 characters, which isn't enough to make a decent watermark this way, so I'm doing something completely different.  Your answer does what it says on the tin though, so have some SO points!

Comment: Curious to what direction you have decided to go?